# Constraint in array character elements in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints, varchar

In PostgreSQL 10.1 I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE nationality_cumulative_criteria
(
    id             smallint NOT NULL,
    country_set    character varying(2)[] NOT NULL,
    number         smallint NOT NULL
);
```

I wish to add a constraint (exclude) which will not allow, for example, "US" to appear in different tuples but only in one.

I have already checked and found only cases with ranges and functions but not with arrays of character elements.

Tia

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you said, do the following:

```
 create unique index on nationality_cumulative_criteria 
 (('US'=any(country_set)))
 where 'US'=any(country_set);
```

This will allow 'US' (specifically) to only be used once in the entire table

Comment: Is there any elegant way to avoid writing this 256 times (the number of array elements)?

Comment: I'm not sure such functionality exists that would work using this method.
You could, however, easily build a trigger that checks all other rows, it'd just depend on how many rows we're talking about, but it sounds like there would be less than 256 rows, and that shouldn't be a big deal (also I infer that this table wouldn't be updated/inserted into often).

If you'd like an example trigger solution, let me know.

Comment: Tal. I am checking if **GIN Indexes** and `array_ops` can help on this matter.

Comment: Unfortunately:

`SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: access method "gin" does not support exclusion constraints`

By using GIST:

`SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: data type character varying[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"

  Hint: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.`